# Describe the elements of a quotient field of a field? EDIT: Field not Group

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let F be a finite field $\mathbb Z_7[x]/(x^3+5)$ how would I go about this. My understanding is that all the powers below $x^3$ get modded out? So we're left with $a+bx+cx^2$ which will leave $7\times7\times7=343$ elements. But I don't understand Why we lose the powers below 3. This is a quotient group under addition right? We're not actually dividing are we?

Comment: Did you mean quotient *field* (vs group)? You lost a $3$, i.e. $7^3 = 343,$ not $34$. But what "powers below $3$" did you lose? What do you mean by that?

Comment: Probably OP means all powers $\ge3$ of $x$ can be reduced down to sums of the powers $1,x,x^2$.

Comment: It is not under addition..It is under multiplication... you see $x^5$ as $x^2.x^3\equiv x^2(-5)$.. you would consider $x^n\equiv x^{3k}.x^{m}$ for $0\leq m\leq 2$ and you see $x^{3k}$ as $(x^3)^k\equiv (-5)^k$.....

Answer (score 0):

For a ring $R$ ($=\mathbb{Z}_7[x]$) and an ideal $I$ ($=(x^3+5)$), the quotient $R/I$ is given by $\left\{r + I : r \in R\right\}$. The element $r + I$ is by definition the set $$r + I = \left\{r + i : i \in I\right\}.$$ Let me repeat for clarity: The elements of $R/I$ are given by sets of the form $r+I$. Now the collection of elements $\left\{r+I : r \in R\right\}$ also have two operations turning them into a ring:
$$(r + I) + (s + I) = (r+s) + I \qquad (r + I) \cdot (s + I) = (r \cdot s) + I.$$ Here, on the RHS of each equality, $r+s$ and $r \cdot s$ are preformed as in the ring $R$.

Now let's see what this means in your example. Take the element $x^3 + I$. Now you should check that $x^3 + I$ gives the same exact set as $-5 + I$. In other words, we have $x^3 + I = -5 + I$ as sets. So these two are the same exact elements of $R/I$. This is why $x^3$ "disappears": any instance of $x^3$ can be replaced by $-5$.

More intuitively, in quotienting out by $(x^3 + 5)$, you are declaring that $x^3 + 5 = 0$ and hence $x^3 = -5$. With this intuition, calculation is easy. For example: $$x \cdot (x^2 + 2x + 1) = x^3 + 2x^2 + x = 2x^2 + x - 5.$$ But it is important to understand the definition of a quotient as it is to see it intuitively.